# Plotly Python - Multiple traces update with slider

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I use Plotly Python.
I have a list of spectrums I want to plot.
This list contains 2d arrays. Each array corresponds to a time frame and contains the spectrums for a certain number of sources (n*m with n number of sources and m length of the spectrums).
Here is a dummy version of that list (random values instead of spectrums):

```py
# List of 1000 arrays/time frames with 20 sources/spectrums each
a = [np.random.rand(20, 5120) for i in range(1000)]
```

So far I’ve been able to plot that for one time frame (one value of the list) only in a plotly plot, by adding n traces to a figure where n is the number of sources I plot.

Now I would like to make it interactive and add a slider to quickly go through the time frames (elements of my list) without having to close the figure, change the frame index and plot for this new time frame.

I found an intermediary solution in this post: [Python: Change Custom Control Values in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976725/2529954).

But it seems, as well as in all the other posts I found on the topic, to just control the visibility parameters of traces. So I guess under the hood it plots everything and just hides or show. And in my case I can have a list of 1000 arrays/time frames, each containing 20 spectrums each. No need to say it’s not doing too well…
Is there any way to do it otherwise?

Below is a snapshot of what I produce at the moment for a single sequence:
[image]

And here is what I achieved by using the solution in the stack overflow solution given above, to show just a few sequences that can be switched with a slider:
[image]

You can reproduce this plot with the following code and with a list of dummy arrays (not actual real spectrums):

```py
# List of 1000 arrays/time frames with 20 sources/spectrums each
a = [np.random.rand(20, 5120) for i in range(1000)] 

# Create figure 
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces, one for each slider step 
for i in np.arange(len(a)):
    for k in range(0, a[i].shape[0]):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode="lines", x=frequencies, y=a[i][k, :], name=f"Source {k}"))

# Create and add slider 
steps = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=["visible", [False] * a[i].shape[0]*len(a)],
    )
    step["args"][1][(i*a[i].shape[0]):(i*a[i].shape[0]+a[i].shape[0])] = [True]*a[i].shape[0]  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=1,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps )]

fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)

# Edit slider labels 
fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['currentvalue']['prefix'] = 'Sequence: ' 
for i in range(len(a)):
    fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['steps'][i]['label'] = i

fig.show()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Antoine

PS: If you no of any way to do this with another library, don't hesitate to share!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to, instead of creating and adding all 20k traces to the figure, create only the 20 traces for the initial frame/step and use the restyle method to update the data in `y` for those existing traces, eg.

```py
# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add one trace per source but for one frame only
istep = 0 # the initial step/frame index
for k in range(0, a[istep].shape[0]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode="lines", x=frequencies, y=a[istep][k], name=f"Source {k}"))

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        label=i,
        args=[dict(
            y=[a[i][k] for k in range(0, a[i].shape[0])]
        )]
    )
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=istep,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Sequence: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps )]

fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders, xaxis_type='log')

fig.show()
```

However, having about 5120 data points per source still appears to be too much, even if we plot 20 traces for one frame, *all* the data (5120 * 20 * 1000 = 102 400 000 points) are passed at once to the front-end via the slider step args which happens to be unsuitable (browser hangs).

From there, I see 2 options, one does not exclude the other :

- Reduce the number of data points: reducing the number of points by a factor of 10 yields something acceptable (nb. it still takes a while to load initially). Assuming you generate FFT data directly from the sources, you could decrease the number of bins (5120/10, increasing the bin width from 5Hz to 50Hz), but you probably don't want that, at least for the low frequencies. Actually the best would be to space the
  frequency bins logarithmically to reduce the data while preserving the visualization accuracy, as it is done by Octave Band analyzer (see [CPB/Octave analysis](https://vibrationresearch.com/blog/octave-analysis-obserview/)).
- Use [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) : you will be able to plot a selection of traces (optionally, among the 20 sources, using a [`dcc.Dropdown`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown) component, not the legend), for a given frame (using [`dcc.Slider`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider) instead of plotly's built-in slider) without having to pass all the data to the client in the first place, by using a dash [callback](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) to update the figure according to the dropdown and slider changes, eg.

  ```
  app = Dash(__name__)

  app.layout = html.Div([
      html.Div([
          'Audio Sources',
          dcc.Dropdown(
              id='source-dropdown',
              multi=True,
              options=[{'label': src, 'value': src} for src in range(20)],
              value=list(range(20)),
              placeholder='Select source(s)',
          )
      ]),
      dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
      html.Div([
          'Frame',
          dcc.Slider(id='frame-slider', min=0, max=999, value=0, step=1,
                  included=False, marks=None, tooltip={'always_visible': True})
      ])
  ])

  @callback(
      Output('graph', 'figure'),
      Input('source-dropdown', 'value'),
      Input('frame-slider', 'value')
  )
  def update_figure(sources, frame):
      fig = go.Figure()
      for k in sources:
          fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode="lines", y=a[frame][k], name=f"Source {k}"))
      fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='log')
      return fig

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply EricLavault!

I can't really change the frequency resolution of my inputs, and for analysis purpose it would not be suitable neither.

I will try to implement option 2 then, although I have never used Dash before, only Plotly. So if you have a draft in mind, please feel free to share.

Anyway thanks again for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated!